# Directing empties with geonodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, empty

There is a cone and two empties. How to make, using geo nodes, so that the base of the cone is attached to one empty, and the top is always directed towards the second empty? Something like "Track to" constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

[image]

and you will get:

[image]

The subtract calculates the direction of the two empties as vector. The align euler to vector transforms that vector to a rotation value.